# Can we use both Z-score standardization and Min-Max scaling as data input for machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning

I am getting better results when I enter as inputs both Z-score standardization and Min-Max scaling. The only worry is when it comes to data selection the algorithm is some time selecting the same feature for both Z-score and Min-Max. Is it a problem? and How to justify that scientifically ??

Comment: what kind(s) of models? How are you measuring the "better results"?

Comment: Classification models (prediction)